# How are Engine Control Units (ECU) of high speed racing bikes coded?

Tags: language-agnostic, embedded

> An engine control unit (ECU), now called the powertrain control module
>   (PCM), is a type of electronic control unit that controls a series of
>   actuators on an internal combustion engine to ensure optimal engine
>   performance. It does this by reading values from a multitude of
>   sensors within the engine bay, interpreting the data using
>   multidimensional performance maps (called lookup tables), and
>   adjusting the engine actuators accordingly.
>   - Wikipedia.
>
> ---
>
> The ECU is a computer, and features many of the same parts as the
>   computer you have at home or at work. There's a microprocessor that
>   receives, interprets and reacts to sensor inputs as fast as they
>   occur. And it's composed of hardware (a pretty standard circuit board)
>   that's encoded with software (a program that tells the car how to
>   run).
>   - HowStuffWorks

I have been reading up on ECUs lately; a side effect of watching too much MotoGP. However, the questions I have are fairly basic:

1. How are these ECUs coded ? (It is okay if you just gloss  over the details rather than diving into the nitty-gritties. I will do the later research) :)
2. What language(s) are generally used ?

Comment: The Stack Exchange sites are for specific questions which can have specific answers.  As you discuss a functional requirement rather than an implementation possibility, many different solutions may exist, making this not a very good fit for the site.  What really sets this apart from other generic embedded controllers is likely the nastiness of the environment (in terms of dirt and electrical noise) in which they must operate.

Comment: @ChrisStratton How do I learn to program embedded systems? So far what I do runs either on my laptop or my phone :)

Comment: Find a cheap (<$30) board and dive in.  An Arduino board is a popular and not bad choice; if you skip the IDE and libraries it's just a commodity ATmega development board.  Many other options exist from other vendors, often substantially more of a hardware capability value but without the same degree of community hand holding.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yep, Arduino was on my mind. You seem to have considerable experience in this field (and Android). I was wondering if there is an embedded Android or likes? That way I will get to study both Android and embedded programming :) I am trying not to divide my energy into two fields simultaneously. :)

Comment: Stock computers are likely written in C or C++ and there is/are coding standards to conform to, etc.  It shouldnt take much googling to find a brand or company that makes them.  For race specific if they dont use the stock computer (they might) then all bets are off it is not a street legal bike, doesnt have zillions of towns, states, provinces, nations laws to conform to.  Lastly it is likely the kind of thing that the handful of folks that started making ECU's back in the day are likely still the incumbents making them now.

Comment: @dwelch Ok I am trying my best to keep the learning curve a little less steep. I am a Java programmer. Is Java used in embedded ?

Comment: these things are not complicated, they need to be simple, the complication is in the electrical side more than the software/digital side.  The power in a car/bike is very noisy and nasty and you have to protect the components from damage due to spikes, and find the good signals out of the noise.  Also you have a very wide expected operating range for temperature from well below freezing to well over 100F probably 200F depending on the location.  The software digital part is not much more than a control system http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_system

Comment: @dwelch Like suggested, I am going to start with Arduino. However, how much of knowledge of electricals and electronics do I need?

Comment: JAVA is not used in this form of embedded, there are instances of JAVA used in embedded.  But these kinds of systems where a software bug can easily kill people, are a little more controlled and C++ is a relatively newly accepted language over something like ADA.

Comment: well you will want to start learning more about that if that is where you want to take this.  the arduino platform is a good place in that it does the vast majority of the work for you if you play in their sandbox.  basically a platform setup to just write apps and not have to really know what is going on.  The beauty of it is that everything is out there in the open and you can if you choose to learn how it all works at your own pace.  Lots of good websites tied to each little sensor not only to show you how to hook it up but to some extent how the thing works electrically.

Comment: For an actual control system you need something to control, something that is going to have outside forces.  Like controlling a motor or controlling the temperature in your house or something (read a temp sensor if the temp is X degrees above the set point the apply X*K amount of umph to the fans or whatever when the temp is Y degrees below the slow down by Y*K. just google control systems and implement a simple one).  You could do this with a light sensor and an led that you drive with a pwm, put your hand over the light sensor it thinks it is darker, your software makes the led brighter

Comment: Although considered a bad control system a light sensor like that should be like some night lights.  it is darker you make the light brighter, the sensor sees that it is brigher makes it darker, the sensor sees it is darker makes it lighter and it oscillates.

Comment: You have to get through the basics, though you need to first be able to build an application, ANY application and download it to the microcontroller board, sometimes this itself is a research project, ideally for arduinos it isnt.  Then learn simple on off led blinking (even if you are not going to do the light thing) just all on all off and learn to time the durations of on and off.  Then learn how to create and how to use a hardware pwm to fine tune the amount of energy being delivered.

Comment: then learn how to read a simple gpio input, button pressed make the light go on or off, button released make the led change state if it ws on make it go off, etc.  Then depending on what you want to do learn how to read the analog imputs, feed it different voltages (now there is a trick how are you going to do that?) and see that it is working, ideally a sensor like a temp sensor or a light sensor, some of them are analog based (some are not).  Those are the basic tools in your tool chest, once you have the basic tools then you can actually go build something with them.

Comment: for each one of these tools, a pwm, an input, etc you can take the already written software from the arduino community, then either while doing that or after it works and you are bored, you can dig in further, understand the registers being programmed, under stand the schematic and the electronics.  all of which the info is out there for free, wikipedia and elsewhere, many of the ardunio like things I mentioned so far are easy to understand, capacitors and resitors and diodes and such and how they affect analog signals, that takes some more math to really understand but there are shortcuts

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52616/discussion-between-little-child-and-dwelch)